# Rails: How to properly prepare variables for view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller

Is there a best practice for preparing variables for a view in Rails?
Basically I want to know if, taking for example a hash like `@campaign`, I should 
extract the needed values (e.g. `list_id`) in the view or in the controller?

```
@campaign = {
             "id"=>"8a9asd64b94", 
             "type"=>"regular", 
             "create_time"=>"2013-04-17T12:07:58+00:00", 
             "recipients"=> {
                             "list_id"=>"aecadsasd0b5", 
                             "segment_text"=>"ljsadlkjasd"
                            }
             }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You typically send the entire object down to the view and access the individual properties there. For example

```
# in controller

@post = Post.find(params[:id])

# in view

<h1><%= @post.title %></h1>
<p><%= @post.body %></p>
```

In your example, you should send the entire `@campaign` object down to the view and access the individual components there.

Comment: Can you explain why? Isn't it especially for big objects unnecessary to pass the whole object and violating the separation of concerns principle to make complicated queries in the view?

Comment: The fetching of data and initialization of objects to hold that data happens in the controller. The view simply reads the attributes on the object - no complex queries happen or should happen in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should do the queries in the controller and pass that to the view. So in your case, `@campaign` should be in the controller, and you can use                 `@campaign["recipients"]["list_id"]` in the view.